# Custom 404 Wordpress with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-fields

I'm running into the following problem. I have a 404.php but I need to use some custom fields on that page. So I preferably need to make a page and use that. But I can't seem to override the default behaviour.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

Remove all the code from the `404.php`

put a single line code of your custom template:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'new-template-name' ); //don't put extension(.php) ?>
```

Here you have to create a new template with the same above mention name

Thanks.

Comment: So I presume I just make a 404-content.php or something, put the custom fields in need in there and then call 404-content with the line of code you provided?

Comment: @LodewijkWensveen that must be working, i have used that in mine project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to accomplish it:

1. Create an empty page template in theme directory named 404-content.php with the following lines of code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: 404 Content */
```

2. Create ACF field group with the desired custom fields for the 404 page (ex. title & contents). The group's post template should be set to "404 Content".
3. Create a 404 page in WP admin. Select the 404 Content as its template, and fill the custom fields with the desired content. Note the post-id of the page created.
4. Update 404.php in your theme directory to display your custom fields. For example (replace xxxx with the post-id of your 404 page):

```
echo get_field('404-page-title', xxxx);
...
echo get_field('404-page-content', xxxx...)
```

Hope that helps someone :)